# How to create a menu in android in Eclips?

Tags: android

good day
I want to create a menu for my android application and use this function in my java file :

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
 }
```

but R.menu does not exsit in R.java file.
please help me.
thank

Comment: You have to create `menu` folder in `res/` folder and create there file `main.xml`

Comment: or you have to add import `your.package.R`

Comment: who want to help me????

Comment: Hi Konrad! thank...but i need to more comment to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a menu folder in you res folder and put a menu.xml file in it.
2. Add some items:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item android:id="@+id/DeleteAccount"
   android:alphabeticShortcut="d"
   android:title="@string/deleteAccount"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/Help"
   android:alphabeticShortcut="i"
   android:title="@string/instructions"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/LogOut"
   android:alphabeticShortcut="l"
   android:title="@string/logout"/>

   </menu>
   ```
3. Add code in the activity where you want the menu:

   ```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   MenuInflater mi= getMenuInflater();
   mi.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
   return true;
   }

   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
   switch (item.getItemId()){
   case R.id.DeleteAccount:
       //open new activity for exemple
       return true;
   case R.id.Help:
       return true;
   case R.id.LogOut:
       return true;
   }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   ```

   }

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi...I do all of your steps and comment that posted, but not show a menu in my phone.Why?..please help me

Comment: You can also search on youtube: add menu android there are some really good tutorials on how to do this

Comment: If you are using fragment then you need to enable the menu inside the constructor/onCreate: 'setHasOptionsMenu (true);'

Answer (score 0):

It can be one of two situations.

First, You really don't have this folder and file, so you have to create it. Create folder `menu` if not exist in folder `res` and int folder `menu` create file main.xml which looks like below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Or second you don't have imports of your `R` class in your class. You have to add it below of `package`

```
  package your.package;

  import your.package.R;
```

Additionally you have to build your project, you can have unset build automatically. Check it as is shown in the image below. If this option is unselected, just set it.

[image]